# Ruby, Nokogiri Remove <ul> element selected by <class="foo">

Tags: html, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I want to remove a Nokogiri node but I don't get it.

I got HTML code like this:

```html
<div class="metis manual-toogle" id="tocList">...
  <li id="tocElement-ebook_cs_1111111_11">...
    <a data-content href="url" class=" "></a> <!-- only this urls I want -->
      <ul class="foo">
        <!-- the following content and urls I want to remove -->
        <li class id="tocElement-ebook_cs_1111111_cs12">
          <a data-content href="url" class=" "></a>
          ...
          <a data-content href="url" class=" "></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

What I've tried so far:

```ruby
document = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html_input)
document.xpath('//ul[@class="foo"]').each {|x| x.remove}

document.xpath('//ul[@class="foo"]').children.map(:&remove)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

I wan't to parse some URL's. I got the html structure like above. The URL I want is in the `<li></li>` block nested like `<a data-content href="url"></a>`. The problem is, inside the `<ul></ul>` is a `<a data-content href="url"></a>` too. I can extract every URL, but only need the main URL's.

It's a book with some chapters, I can download the chapter with the first link. Every sub-chapter (inside the `<ul>`) got a own pdf.

I can't use regular expression because the links are not build the same. For example in one book it's

- chapter 1 pdf: `...-ch1.pdf` (contains all sub-chapter)

  - chapter 1-1 pdf: `...-ch1-1.pdf`
- chapter 2 pdf: `...-923df2.pdf`
- chapter 3 pdf: `...-ch3.pdf`

The HTML-Code is a mess. The easiest way is to remove the `<ul>` block itself.

Comment: I don't think you can edit the html using nokogiri, it's s parsing gem. But still I am unsure. Did you get any error for your code?

Comment: "I don't get it" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing much context or detail here. But, the following code should remove the item you want if you are selecting it correctly. Please provide more details such as your output received, output expected, etc.

Given the limited information, you could try this bit:

UPDATE:

html.html

```
<div class="metis manual-toogle" id="tocList">...
  <li id="tocElement-ebook_cs_1111111_11">...
    <a data-content href="url" class=" "></a> <!-- only this urls I want -->
      <ul class="foo">
        <!-- the following content and urls I want to remove -->
        <li class id="tocElement-ebook_cs_1111111_cs12">
          <a data-content href="url" class=" "></a>
          ...
          <a data-content href="url" class=" "></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

main.rb

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('html.html'))

doc.xpath('//ul[@class="foo"]').remove

doc.xpath('//a').each do |item|
puts item
end
```

Output:

```
~/code/projects/test ⌚ 8:28:32
$ ruby main.rb                                                                                                                                                                                                          ‹2.6.1›
<a data-content href="urliwant" class=" "></a>
```

We worked this out through chat. Above example works. But, for his specific case we needed to do this because of the messy html:

```
document = Nokogiri::HTML(open('html.html'))

document.css('//ul//ul//ul').remove
document.css('ul .collapse').remove

links = document.xpath('//*[@id="toc"]//ul')

File.open("input.html", "a") do |output_txt|
  links.each do |item|
    output_txt.write(item)
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately this don't works. `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
                        ul.children.map(:&remove)`

Comment: @Patrick you updated the OP. Give me a few mins and I'll update this answer.

Comment: thank you for your help, I appreciated that.
But the code don't remove the `ul`-blocks with the class
If I put a `puts item` in the `.each` loop there is no output

Comment: @Patrick to get the links inside of the ul class foo, you can do `doc.xpath('//ul[@class="foo"]//a')`

Comment: @Patrick updated one more time for you about getting the links in the UL

Comment: @Patrick then youre using the incorrect xpath. If you could paste the actual document code here I can help. But, with the example given, that's the best I can do. I can puts out the items from the example on my end. So, your xpath isnt correct. Might be easier to use .css instead of .xpath too, imo.

Comment: the code is too long, but it have this structure:
```
<div class="tabContainer navBox">
 <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="toc" class="tab-pane fade active in">
   <ul class="metis manual-toggle" id="tocList">
    <li id="tocElement-ebook_cs_1111111_cs11">
     <a data-content href="url" class=" ">
      <ul class="collapse">
       <li class_id="tocElement-ebook_cs_1111111_cs12" class=" ">
         <a data-content href="url" class=" ">
       ..... more entries
```

Comment: I want the code from the first `<a data-content href="url">`, the export is going well, I get *all* the links, but want only the ones outside the `<ul class="collapse">`, the `collapse` is the `foo` in my example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217313/discussion-between-patrick-and-nolyoi).